# a use statement is not allowed in a procedure, function or trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I've got the following code I've put together which seems to work just fine.  However, I need to put it within a stored procedure, but I get the following error:

**a use statement is not allowed in a procedure, function or trigger**

Anyone know of a work around?

---

```
CREATE TABLE #TableRowCounts1
(
      [TableName] VARCHAR(128), 
      [RowCount] INT
) 

CREATE TABLE #TableRowCounts2
(
      [TableName] VARCHAR(128), 
      [RowCount] INT
) 

use Database1
GO

INSERT INTO #TableRowCounts1
(
      [TableName], 
      [RowCount]
      )
EXEC sp_MSforeachtable 
      'SELECT ''?'' 
      [TableName], 
      COUNT(*) [RowCount] 
      FROM ?'

use Database2
GO

INSERT INTO #TableRowCounts2
(
      [TableName], 
      [RowCount]
      )
EXEC sp_MSforeachtable 
      'SELECT ''?'' 
      [TableName], 
      COUNT(*) [RowCount] 
      FROM ?'
```

---

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should change it to work like that. You need to specify the fully qualified name by using the database (and schema) in front of the stored procs you want to run on different databases.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SomeProc

AS

CREATE TABLE #TableRowCounts1
(
      [TableName] VARCHAR(128), 
      [RowCount] INT
) 

CREATE TABLE #TableRowCounts2
(
      [TableName] VARCHAR(128), 
      [RowCount] INT
) 

INSERT INTO #TableRowCounts1
(
      [TableName], 
      [RowCount]
      )
EXEC Database1.[dbo].sp_MSforeachtable 
      'SELECT ''?'' 
      [TableName], 
      COUNT(*) [RowCount] 
      FROM ?'

INSERT INTO #TableRowCounts2
(
      [TableName], 
      [RowCount]
      )
EXEC Database2.[dbo].sp_MSforeachtable 
      'SELECT ''?'' 
      [TableName], 
      COUNT(*) [RowCount] 
      FROM ?'
```

Comment: Doh! Completely missed that. Thanks .

Answer (score 5):

Instead of using USE statement you can simply use a fully qualified name i.e

```
DATABASENAME.SCHEMANAME.TABLENAME.ColumnName
```